# MySQL joining table's maximum row contents

Tags: mysql, sql

For a simple forum I would like to list the threads in order from most recent post. That I have completed with no issue with the following query:

```
SELECT t.thread_id, t.title, MAX(m.post_id) as latest_reply
FROM forum_thread as t
    LEFT JOIN forum_post as n ON(latest_reply = m.thread_id)

WHERE t.forum_id=:forum_id AND t.sticky=0
GROUP BY t.thread_id
ORDER BY latest_reply DESC
LIMIT :limit_bottom, :limit_top
```

This works fine, until I want more details from the maximum post row. If I select more info from the post table, the results are random

I would like to also know, the post title, and then the username who posted.

The thread table [forum_thread] looks like the following:

```
thread_id | forum_id | title | sticky | post_count | view_count | closed
```

The  post table [forum_post] looks like the following:

```
post_id | user_id | thread_id | timestamp | title | post_body_cache
```

And the user table [user] looks like the following:

```
id | username
```

I need to join the maximum post row to get the title, and than join the user table to get the username. What is the most efficient way of doing this? Everything I have tried has returned a fatal error.

Desired results would be:

```
[forum_thread] thread_id | [forum_thread] title | [forum_post] MAX post_id | [forum_post] title | [user] username
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the entire row from the outer table, you have to move the Max to a subquery and use it in the joining criteria:

```
SELECT  t.thread_id, t.title, p.author, p.post_date, p.whatever
FROM    forum_thread as t
LEFT JOIN forum_post as p
    ON  p.thread_id = m.thread_id
    and p.post_date =(
        select  Max( p.post_date )
        from    forum_post
        where   thread_id = p.thread_id )    
WHERE   t.forum_id = :forum_id
    AND t.sticky= 0
```